# When full screen is applied in javaFx the controllers doesnt adjust to the screen

Tags: javafx, screen, builder, scene

Im doing my 1st JavaFx project using scene builder 2.0. When I set the fullscreen method true, the anchor pane goes to full screen but the controllers inside the container doesn't adjust according to the  adjusted pane size. It will be a great help if someone could point me out where I have messed up.
This is the code I have used in the main program.

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D r = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
    String css = this.getClass().getResource("newCascadeStyleSheet.css").toExternalForm(); 






    stage.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    stage.show();
}
```

Ive set the sizes padding and everything using scene builder options.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sizing nodes is a layout operation.  If you have a layout question which is related to fxml, you have to supply your fxml in the question, as fxml defines your layout.  Without fxml the question is unanswerable.  For further assistance, you should supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is both minimal and complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is a *Fit to parent* setting in your view.
As you are using SceneBuilder, I suggest you to try the following: in the *Hierarchy* view (left side) right-click your component and select *Fit to parent*.
This is an example (taken from [this awesome tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/)):
[image]

Comment: I found the answer @zxxz thanx for your support. I did not know that option too. helped me in several other occasions.The problem i had was in the layout option of the controllers... i had to add anchor pane constrains. thanx to all